# Product of Bernoulli Random Variables

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

[image: Please click here for the link to the question]

I am stuck on "part (a)" of this question.

My approach:

X, Y and Z are independent Bernoulli random variables.

So, XYZ is also a Bernoulli random variable, since it can take only two values - {0,1}
(1 when all of them are 1 and 0 when any of X, Y or Z is 0)

Therefore P(XYZ = 0) = 1 - {0.5*0.5*0.5} = 7/8

Now, 7/8 = 0.875, which is greater than 3/4 or 0.75.

But I don't think this is the right approach to solving this question, since I wasn't able to arrive at the inequality explicitly.

I would be very grateful, if somebody can help me with this question.

Comment: You don't seem to realize this fact: Pairwise independence is _weaker_ than complete independence.  I.e. the problem statement only gave you enough to conclude that $P(XY=1) = P(X=1)P(Y=1) = 1/4$ and $P(YZ=1) = P(Y=1)P(Z=1) = 1/4$ and $P(ZX=1) = P(Z=1)P(X=1) = 1/4$.  However, the problem stmt does _not_ give you enough to conclude that $P(XYZ=1) = P(X=1)P(Y=1)P(Z=1) = 1/8$.  In fact the $Z$ defined in part (b) is the classic example of pairwise independence but not complete independence.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Oh, no, you were informed that the variables are pairwise independent, *but* that does *not* assure you that they will be *mutually* independent.

So you *cannot* justify saying: $\mathsf P(XYZ{=}1)=\mathsf P(X{=}1)\mathsf P(Y{=}1)\mathsf P(Z{=}1)$.   It *may* not be true (and indeed, part (b) indicates that it *will* not be true).

However, you can say $\mathsf P(XYZ{=}0) = \mathsf P(X{=}0\cup Y{=}0\cup Z{=}0)$ and then use the *principle of inclusion and exclusion* to express this as a series of seven terms.   The information given will allow you to evaluate six of these seven terms, and there *is* an *inequality* you do know about the seventh *propability measure*.

Go to it.

Comment: Oh, alright!

Thank you so much for the help!